# laravel pretty url issue on my azure vm

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, azure, mod-rewrite

I have added the .htaccess file on my azure vm `/public` folder like the laravel 4.2 documentation stated...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

...and i have enabled the `mod_rewrite` module but still no progress @ http://popibay.com/login what works is http://popibay.com/index.php/login please i need your assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that `.htaccess` file is not being used by apache.

To test, add something like `Redirect 301 / http://google.com/` to the beginning of `.htaccess` and see if it redirects there when you access your site.

If it doesn't ensure that your `<Directory>` configuration has `AllowOverride All`. That instructs apache to use/respect `.htaccess`. Default is usually `AllowOverride None`

Comment: Thanks this work, i have set the AllowOverride All  httpd.conf file that made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be something unconfigured. And I found the same issue with you in http://www.epigroove.com/blog/laravel-routes-not-working-make-sure-htaccess-is-working.

In general, 
This will change the `AllowOverride` value for all your websites. In your **httpd.conf** file, look for the main `<Directory>` directive:

`<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ...
    AllowOverride None
    ...
</Directory>`

Simply change it to this:

`<Directory "/var/www/html">
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>`

I modified `AllowOverride` from “**All**” to “**None**”, and I succeeded to reproduce your issue. So I think it is the key to your problem.